# Pipe and Process management

Tags: c, shell, pipe, waitpid

I am working on a tiny shell(tsh) implemented in C(it's an assignment). One part of assignment belongs to PIPING. I have to pipe a command's output to another command. e.g:`ls -l | sort`

When I run the shell, every command that I execute on it, is processed by a child process that it spawns. After the child finishes the result is returned.  For piping I wanted to implement a harcoded example first to check how it works. I wrote a method, that partially works. The problems is when I run the pipe command, after child process finishes, the whole program quits with it! Obviously I am not handling the child process signal properly(Method code below).

### My Question:

- How does process management with pipe() works? if i run a command `ls -l | sort` does it create a child process for `ls -l` and another process for `sort` ? From the piping examples that I have seen so far, only one process is created(fork()).
- When the second command (`sort` from our example) is processed, how can i get its process ID?

EDIT: Also while running this code I get the result twice. don't know why it runs twice, there is no loop in there.

Here is my code:

```
pid_t pipeIt(void){
    pid_t pid;
    int pipefd[2];

    if(pipe(pipefd)){
        unix_error("pipe");
        return -1;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) <0){
        unix_error("fork");
        return -1;  
    }
    if(pid == 0){
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1],1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        if(execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *)NULL) < 0){
            unix_error("/bin/ls");
            return -1;
        }// End of if command wasn't successful

    }// End of pid == 0
    else{
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0],0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        if(execl("/usr/bin/tr", "tr", "e", "f", (char *)NULL) < 0){
            unix_error("/usr/bin/tr");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return pid;

}// End of pipeIt
```

Comment: You *may* find [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356075/toy-shell-not-piping-correctly) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the shell must fork to exec each subprocess.  Remember that when you call one of the `execve()` family of functions, it *replaces* the current process image with the exec'ed one.  Your shell cannot continue to process further commands if it directly execs a subprocess, because thereafter it no longer exists (except as the subprocess).

To fix it, simply `fork()` again in the `pid == 0` branch, and exec the `ls` command in that child.  Remember to `wait()` for both (all) child processes if you don't mean the pipeline to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Any hints on why the process is running several times? I tried to encapsulate it in do - while(waitpid>0) but that didn't work. Can you elaborate a bit on the wait() function?

Comment: For full details you should really consult the manual (section 2, not section 1).  Basically, though, the `wait()` (or `waitpid()`) syscalls suspend execution of the calling process until the state of a child process changes.  Typically it's used to wait for a child process to terminate, but if you ask it to do so it can also detect when the child is suspended or resumed by a signal.  You will want to `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each child process to exit (one wait per child).

Comment: I can't speak to your multiple processes question without seeing code, but do note that the whole point of the exercise is to have one child process for *each* command in the pipeline.  If that's what you in fact see then it's all good, but if you see more than that then you do have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to call fork at least twice, once for each program in the pipeline. Remember that exec replaces the program image of the current process, so your shell stops existing the moment you start running sort or (tr).

Comment: You're off to a good start, you just need another call to fork in the else-bit. I see that the function is supposed to return a pid, I guess the pid of the last process is good enough. What real shells do is create a dedicated subshell for the pipeline but that may be overkill.