# Problems with pipes in c

Tags: c, pipe

I got a problem with pipes. I am trying to execute for example ls | grep test and my program freezes. My program is a shell program and i got redirect and other things to work, but i can't get pipes to work... What am i doing wrong?? I have search for answers but can't find any that fix my problem.

```
if(pipe(fd_pipe) < 0)
        perror("pipe error...");

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) /* fork a child process */
    {     
        perror("ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) /* the child process, do the first command */
    {  
        printf("In first child...\n");
        //dupPipe(fd_pipe, 1, STDOUT_FILENO);   /* send to write end of pipe */

        fflush(stdout);
        std_out = dup(1); // for later restore...
        close(fd_pipe[0]);
        dup2(fd_pipe[1], 1);


        printf("exec %s in first child...\n", comline[0].argv[0]);         
        if (execvp(comline[0].argv[0], comline[0].argv) < 0) /* execute the command  */
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"-mish: Exe of %s failed...",comline[0].argv[0]);
            fflush(stderr);
            perror("");
        }

    }
    else    /* parent process*/
    {
        while (wait(&status) != pid)    //wait for child to completion
            ;

        fflush(stdin);
        std_in = dup(0); // for later restore...
        close(fd_pipe[1]);
        dup2(fd_pipe[0], 0);


        if (execvp(comline[1].argv[0], comline[1].argv) < 0) /* execute the command  */
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"-mish: Exe of %s failed...",comline[0].argv[0]);
                fflush(stderr);
                perror("");
            }
```

Comment: Technically, calling `fflush` on `stdin` is undefined. If you want to be portable then don't do it.

Comment: "I have search for answer" - search harder. [Did you see this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356075/toy-shell-not-piping-correctly)?

Comment: Note that you don't need to test the return value of `execvp()` or any of its family.  If the function returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it doesn't return.  Your comment about 'for later restore' is odd; there isn't going to be any 'later' to do the restore if the `execvp()` succeeds.  A clearer comment would be 'for restore if the command fails to execute', but it would be more convincing if you showed the code.

Comment: You might also observe that `perror()` returns to the calling code, so if the pipe fails, you still try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the comments in [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32028697/15168) apply in the long term — you need to run all the programs in a pipeline concurrently to ensure that there aren't any deadlocks because one process is trying to write to a full pipe and another is waiting for the one process to complete before executing the code (or program) that reads from the pipe.  The comments made directly under the question also apply.

However, this code, derived from yours with minimal band-aiding (I did comment out the unused variables `std_in` and `std_out`, though), compiles cleanly and runs and produces plausible output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct cmd
{
    char **argv;
};

int main(void)
{
    int fd_pipe[2];
    int pid;
    //int std_in;
    //int std_out;
    int status;
    char *cmd1[] = { "ls", 0 };
    char *cmd2[] = { "grep", "test", 0 };
    struct cmd comline[2] = { { cmd1 }, { cmd2 } };

    if(pipe(fd_pipe) < 0)
        perror("pipe error...");

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) /* fork a child process */
    {     
        perror("ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) /* the child process, do the first command */
    {  
        printf("In first child...\n");
        //dupPipe(fd_pipe, 1, STDOUT_FILENO);   /* send to write end of pipe */

        fflush(stdout);
        //std_out = dup(1); // for later restore...
        close(fd_pipe[0]);
        dup2(fd_pipe[1], 1);

        printf("exec %s in first child...\n", comline[0].argv[0]);         
        if (execvp(comline[0].argv[0], comline[0].argv) < 0) /* execute the command  */
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"-mish: Exe of %s failed...",comline[0].argv[0]);
            fflush(stderr);
            perror("");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    else    /* parent process*/
    {
        while (wait(&status) != pid)    //wait for child to completion
            ;

        fflush(stdin);
        //std_in = dup(0); // for later restore...
        close(fd_pipe[1]);
        dup2(fd_pipe[0], 0);

        if (execvp(comline[1].argv[0], comline[1].argv) < 0) /* execute the command  */
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"-mish: Exe of %s failed...",comline[0].argv[0]);
            fflush(stderr);
            perror("");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Exiting from %d\n", (int)getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

In a directory with 130-odd files (giving about 1.5 KiB of output from `ls`), I get:

```
$ ./p97
In first child...
chk-utf8-test.sh
chk-wchar-test.sh
pbb-test.data
test-fstatat.c
test-rename.c
utf8-test.c
wchar-test.c
$
```

This is what I get from the command line running `ls | grep test` apart (of course) from the diagnostic message.

My suspicion, though, is that you've not shown us all the code.  The `std_in` and `std_out` variables make me suspicious that there is actually some other code around, and maybe the `pipe()` operation is occurring in a parent process which then forks, and the child then runs the rest of the code shown in the question.  If there is a scenario like that, then there could be problems with commands not completing because the pipe is not properly closed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works now :). The std_in and std_out was to restore it back to STDIN and STDOUT for later use. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `wait()` while the first child process is still running.  That means that there's nothing reading anything the first child writes to its `stdout` - if the pipe fills up, the first child process will block writing to `stdout`.  But since the parent process is `wait()`'ing for the first child to end, you wind up in a deadlock.

Comment: This is (at least) a potential problem; it will need to be addressed.  The elements of a pipeline should run concurrently.  I'm not sure it's the only problem, nor will be a problem if the output of `ls` is less than about 5 KiB, which is quite a large directory listing.