# How can I capture the output?

Tags: c, file, fork, exec, dup2

I have a C program that is calling another one, just like

```
system("path/program2 path/file.txt");
```

So that program can handle a instruction file. That program gives information that I want to use on my C program but I don't have the source of "program2" so I can't edit it.

Currently I'm making "program2" to write in a file (I can choose between showing info on console or writing to file) and the on my C program I open the file then read, but I think maybe it's possible to make it better than that but I'm really rusty on C...

Can anyone give some ideas and/or advice?

Thanks!

---

EDIT

As some of you suggested, I looked at `fork()`, `exec()` and `dup2()` functions and I think I have a better method now for sharing information.

So, until now I had this:

- program1 makes `system()` call to run `program2`
- program2 creates a temp file `temp.txt` and writes information
- back in program1, it opens `temp.txt`, read and manipulate information.

That makes 2 open's and 2 close's

Now, with theese functions, I can do

- program1 makes open a handler to `temp.txt`
- program1 makes `fork()` to replicate itself
- on program1.child, a `dup2()` function is called to redirect standard input to `temp.txt`
- on program1.child a `exec()` function is called to run `program2`
- program2 makes its work and display all the info (that will be redirected to `temp.txt`
- while all this, program1.father will `wait()` until program1.child ends
- on the end, program.father will read the file contents and use the data

I think this procedure could be valid, but I still have a flaw - using a file.

I want this program to run on a server, so I think using files can be confusing even dangerous... but still this method is way better than the one I was using so until I find something better I bet I can make a way to manage file creation on the server side...

So, is the "new" procedure valid?

---

FINAL EDIT:

So, with `popen()` all the issue is solved.

```
FILE *in;
extern FILE *popen();
char buff[512];

if(!(in = popen("path/program2 path/file.txt", "r"))){
    //error;
}

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL){
    printf("%s", buff);
}

pclose(in);
```

(extracted from sw-at.com)

Thank you all for your help! I learned some things today!

Comment: Don't use `system`. Create a new process to execute `program2`, and just set up its `stdout` to pipe into your `program1`.

Comment: I just google it... Do you mean fork()  function?

Comment: If you are on a POSIX system then yes. If not, then consult your OS's developer documentation.

Comment: If on one of the unices (and judging by those paths, you are) `pipe` `dup2` `fork` something out of the `exec` family, and `wait`, will probably do what you want when married together appropriately. An admittedly self-serving example [can be seen **here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19357317/1322972). That example chains three processes together. Yours would obviously be a little less convoluted.

Comment: You can also take a look at popen() function. It works for 1 direction pipe only, but a lot easier to use than fork/dup2/etc..  In your case you could use it to read the stdout of program2 just like you would read a file.

Comment: @mgagnon short and clear. You gave me a really good hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of to achieve what you desire without using a temporary file.

1. Using UNIX Shell

If you are on *nix then you can simply execute both the programs as:

```
    $ ./prog2 | ./prog1
```

Where `prog2` writes to `stdout` and `prog1` reads from `stdin`. `|` character creates a pipe, an unidirection channel between `prog1` and `prog2` which directly feds the output of `prog2` to `prog1` without using temporary file.

2. Without using Shell

   2.1) In `prog2` create a `pipe`:

   ```
   int pipefd[2];
   pipe(pipefd);
   ```

   2.2) Then `fork` the `prog2`

   ```
   fork()
   ```

   2.3) Next, in child `exec` `prog1` with `pipefd[0]` as an argument

   ```
   char buffer[10];
   snprintf(buffer, 10, "%s", pipefd[0]);
   int execl("./prog1", "./prog1", buffer, (char *)0);
   ```

   2.4) Now in `prog2` write to `pipefd[1]` and in `prog1` read from `pipefd[0]`

In `prog1` you need to use `atoi()` to retrieve the `pipefd[0]`

```
    foo = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Now read from `foo`.

Comment: Hi. Please keep in mind that I cannot modify "program2" since I have no source code.

Comment: @DavidSoléGonzález So why not use the shell `pipe` operator? I guess if you don't have access to the source **and** you don't want to use a temorary file then that's the only way.

Comment: I can't use pipes here, I'm not launching program1 directly by shell, it's a Apache plug-in handler in which I'm working. Thanks for your time :)