# I want to create two communication between parent and child residing in different C files using ordinary pipes (IPC)

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

I am trying to send message from parant.c to child.c and I am successfully receiving it in the child.c
My question is that how can I send message back to the parent using second pipe from child.c I want the exact sequence of code.

Here is my parent.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    char buf[] = "HELLO WORLD!", receive[100];
    if (pipe(fd))
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return -1;
    }
    switch (fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    case 0:
        // child
        close(fd[1]);              // close write end
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); // redirect stdin to read end
        close(fd[0]);             // close read end
        execl("./child", NULL); // execute child

    default:
        // parent
        close(fd[0]);                   // close read end
        write(fd[1], buf, sizeof(buf)); // write to write end
        close(fd[1]);                   // close write end
        wait(NULL);
    }

    printf("\nEND~\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am sending buf ("Hello world") to the child by executing ./child file.
Here is my child.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid = fork();
    char buf[100], child_msg[] = "From Child: Hello Parent";
    if (pipe(fd))
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return -1;
    }
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    case 0:

        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("%s ", buf);
        close(fd[1]);
    default:
        wait(NULL);
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving Hello world in this file. but now how can I send child_msg back to the parent? I don't how to do that. I am stuck at this for last 14 hours.

Comment: Stand up another pipe. If you know how the code you posted works, it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I know how this code works. But I am not able to send message back from child. I am trying the same way but did not work.

Comment: At the risk of sounding self-gratifying, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19357317/1322972) helpful. It isn't C (it's C++), but the pipe work is what you're interested in, and that transcends that condition.

Comment: Do you intentionally have fall-through cases in your switches?

Comment: Yes would they gonna create Problem?

Answer (score 1):

From `main pipe`:

```
pipe() creates a pipe, a unidirectional data channel ...
```

So, you need 2 pipes, i.e., you have to create 2 pipes *in your main process* that will also be inherited by the child process.

From your code, you are `exec`ing another program, in such cases you might
be better off with other IPCs and not pipe!

Comment: But I have to use Ordinary Pipes

Comment: Go ahead and use 2 "ordinary" pipes - one for each direction